# Why data apears only after restart the app?

Tags: android, auto-update, insert-update

I made small app that gets some values from the user and display it in custom listview in another activity (2nd) after pressing the button in the 1st activity.
The situation now it's works but only after I closing the app and reopen it.
I want it will work immediately after I press the button.
Can someone help me with this issue please ?

mainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private exampleAdapter mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setInsertButton();
        loadData();
        buildRecyclerView();
    }
    private void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    private void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences8", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list8", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<exampleItem>>() {
        }.getType();
        mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if (mExampleList == null) {
            mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences8", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(mExampleList);
        editor.putString("task list8", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void setInsertButton() {
        Button buttonInsert = findViewById(R.id.insert2);
        buttonInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText line1 = findViewById(R.id.categ2);
                final EditText lineimg = findViewById(R.id.summ2);
                final EditText line2 = findViewById(R.id.date22);

                String lin1 = line1.getText().toString();
                String lin2 = line2.getText().toString();
                String lin3 = lineimg.getText().toString();

                mExampleList.add(new exampleItem(lin1, lin3, lin2));
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mExampleList.size());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                saveData();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

mainActivity2

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {



    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private exampleAdapter mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        setInsertButton();
        loadData();
        //buildRecyclerView();
}
    private void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    private void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences8", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list8", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<exampleItem>>() {
        }.getType();
        mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if (mExampleList == null) {
            mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences8", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(mExampleList);
        editor.putString("task list8", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
        private void setInsertButton() {
            Button buttonInsert = findViewById(R.id.insert);
            buttonInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final EditText line1 = findViewById(R.id.categ);
                    final EditText lineimg = findViewById(R.id.summ);
                    final EditText line2 = findViewById(R.id.date2);

                    String lin1 = line1.getText().toString();
                    String lin2 = line2.getText().toString();
                    String lin3 = lineimg.getText().toString();


                    
                    mExampleList.add(new exampleItem(lin3, lin2, lin1));
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mExampleList.size());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    
                    saveData();
                    finish();

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Adapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class exampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<exampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextViewLine1;
        public TextView mTextViewLine2;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewLine1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line1);
            mTextViewLine2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line2);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icond);
        }
    }
    public exampleAdapter(ArrayList<exampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        exampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        holder.mTextViewLine1.setText(currentItem.getLine1());
        holder.mTextViewLine2.setText(currentItem.getLine2());
        if (currentItem.getLineimg().equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.salary);
        }
        if (currentItem.getLineimg().equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.money);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside loadData() you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the mAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

In the class MainActivity under the function "loadData()" you must update the adapter notifying that the data has changed.

The function (loadData()) should look something like:

```
private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared 
    preferences8", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list8", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<exampleItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if (mExampleList == null) {
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```